# Appium throws Error while tapping an visible drop-down item on Android Device/Emulator

Tags: android, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Hello Appium Developers,

I have an issue while tapping an visible drop-down item , please find the below details to replicate the issue

Steps followed to automate:-

1. Tap on the drop-down image to lists the items.      --- Taping is working fine here
2. Check for the drop-down items listed                     ---- Required items are listed and visible
3. Tap on the required drop-down item                         ---  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the        command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
   Command duration or timeout: 240 milliseconds

Note:- I have tried with Click,flick etc but all events shows appium error.

Can anyone share your thoughts on this ?? Am i missing anything....

Really Appreciate your inputs.......

URL :-http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/Pk7SP/

Code snippet:-

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Nancy Davolio')]"));
 new TouchActions(driver).singleTap(element).perform();
```

Appium Logs:-

```
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13
769/touch/click
debug: Request received with params: {"element":"0.4438802069053054-1"}
debug: Proxying command to 127.0.0.1:9515
info: Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/sessio
n/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/touch/click","method":"POST","json":{"element
":"0.4438802069053054-1"}}
debug: Proxied response received with status 200: {"sessionId":"9f30590c753d7d2f
7c7262f7b6d13769","status":0,"value":null}
POST /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/touch/click 200 588ms - 85
b
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13
769/element
debug: Request received with params: {"using":"xpath","value":".//*[@id='dropdow
nlistContentcombobox']/input"}
debug: Proxying command to 127.0.0.1:9515
info: Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/sessio
n/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/element","method":"POST","json":{"using":"xpa
th","value":".//*[@id='dropdownlistContentcombobox']/input"}}
debug: Proxied response received with status 200: {"sessionId":"9f30590c753d7d2f
7c7262f7b6d13769","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.4438802069053054-2"}}
POST /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/element 200 182ms - 124b
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13
769/element/0.4438802069053054-2/click
debug: Request received with params: {"id":"0.4438802069053054-2"}
debug: Proxying command to 127.0.0.1:9515
info: Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/sessio
n/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/element/0.4438802069053054-2/click","method":
"POST","json":{"id":"0.4438802069053054-2"}}
debug: Proxied response received with status 200: {"sessionId":"9f30590c753d7d2f
7c7262f7b6d13769","status":0,"value":null}
POST /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/element/0.4438802069053054
-2/click 200 435ms - 85b
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13
769/element
debug: Request received with params: {"using":"xpath","value":"//td[contains(tex
t(),'Nancy Davolio')]"}
debug: Proxying command to 127.0.0.1:9515
info: Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/sessio
n/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/element","method":"POST","json":{"using":"xpa
th","value":"//td[contains(text(),'Nancy Davolio')]"}}
debug: Proxied response received with status 200: {"sessionId":"9f30590c753d7d2f
7c7262f7b6d13769","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.4438802069053054-3"}}
POST /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/element 200 118ms - 124b
debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13
769/touch/click
debug: Request received with params: {"element":"0.4438802069053054-3"}
debug: Proxying command to 127.0.0.1:9515
info: Making http request with opts: {"url":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/sessio
n/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/touch/click","method":"POST","json":{"element
":"0.4438802069053054-3"}}
info: Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unkno
wn server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"unknow
n error: Element is not clickable at point (89, 51). Other element would receive
 the click: <div class=\"overlay\" style=\"z-index: 99; -webkit-appearance: none
; background-color: black; opacity: 0.01; outline: none; border: none; padding:
0px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; wid
th: 256px; height: 198px; background-position: initial initial; background-repea
t: initial initial;\"></div>\n  (Session info: chrome=34.0.1847.114)\n  (Driver
info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)"},"sessionId":
"9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769"}
POST /wd/hub/session/9f30590c753d7d2f7c7262f7b6d13769/touch/click 500 219ms - 74
4b
```

Comment: try this :.//*[@id='dropdownlistArrowcombobox']/div.click();

Answer (score 0):

unknow
n error: Element is not clickable at point (89, 51). Other element would receive
 the click:

From logs it seems that while clicking on the element some loader kind of stuff runs , appium is trying to click on the element when loader is still loading stuffs. So you can wait for some time by Thread.sleep or put some logic to wait till `<div class='overlay'` element disappears.